# Tracking the use of my Javascript

Tags: javascript, tracking

Is there a way to track if my javascript code is being used on another site?

I work for a software development company and although I'm not a developer as such I do get involved with some of the more simple Javascript requests we get from our customers.

However, sometimes our customers want to see the Javascript working before agreeing to pay for it. My problem here is that although they are not going to be very technical they may have enough knowledge to look at the page source and effectively 'steal' the script.

Can I either prevent them from doing this or add some kind of tracking to my code somewhere so if they do a simple copy / paste then I can receive notification somehow of the script being used on another site?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, but they can just remove it.

Comment: Obviously.. but I'm working on the basis that although they may have enough knowledge to copy and paste from the page source they will not want to start editing the script itself for fear of it then not working.

Comment: Just say no. This is like asking to test drive a car that isn't built yet. Sure, if the car was already on the lot you could take it for a spin, but it hasn't even come out of the factory yet.

Comment: @ChrisShouts - it could be that it is already built and they want to verify it works as advertised before paying for the job. That's a perfectly reasonable request. This is yet another reason why having a signed contract **before work begins** is essential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things you can do:

- Obfuscate your code so it'll be harder to find out what to copy for non technical people.
- Add a line that checks the domain name of the page and throws an exception or does some other trick to terminate if the domain is not your demo server.
- Add an Ajax query to your server to validate that the script is allowed to run and terminate if there is no validation.

All said here will only protect against non-technical people. Javascript is an interpreted language and as such the entire code is sent to the browser. A skilled programmer will know to go around your blockings.

Answer (score 1):

it is not easy to track your script over all www but there are ways to protect your js codes. there are plenty of sites for encoding and obfuscation like the site below:

http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx

They would still be able to use your codes but you can hide some protection codes in obfuscated version like trial timeout values or even posting some values like site url to your server for tracking.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> our customers want to see the Javascript working before agreeing to pay for it.
> ```

You can achieve a good level of security by setting up a demo machine.  Have the users remote into a session to provide a demo of the product.  Ideally, a shared session where you can "walk them through it" (aka watch what they are doing).

Similar to a video conference, but this way they can use the browser.  Don't make the site public, run the webserver local only (close port 80 on the firewall). Take the remote desktop server down after the demo and change the password.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM API to a `<script>` tag that points to a server-side script on your server and append it to the `<head>`.

Using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://yourserver.com/TrackScript', { url: document.location });
```

Comment: This just adds another step to bypass for any potential thief.  After they download the script its just a matter of copy/paste into their own personal *.js file.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I know; I already said that in my comment on the question.